# Select column with only one negative value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to select the columns that only have one negative value or none. How can I construct this looking at this example? I've been searching for something similar, didn't succeed though. Thanks for any help.

```
N = 5
np.random.seed(0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
          {'X':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
           'Y':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
           'Z':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
                })

          X         Y         Z
0  0.292881  0.875365  1.750350
1  1.291136 -0.374477  0.173370
2  0.616580  2.350638  0.408267
3  0.269299  2.781977  2.553580
4 -0.458071 -0.699351 -2.573784
```

So in this example I'd like to return columns X and Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iloc to do that i.e

```
df1.iloc[:,((df1<0).sum(0) <= 1).values]
```

or (Thanks Jon)

```
df1.loc[:,df1.lt(0).sum() <= 1]
```

Output:

```
          X         Z
0  0.292881  1.750350
1  1.291136  0.173370
2  0.616580  0.408267
3  0.269299  2.553580
4 -0.458071 -2.573784
```

Comment: Yeah, I assumed OP needed only col names.

Comment: Or use `df1.loc[:,df1.lt(0).sum() <= 1]` instead of `iloc`

Comment: @JonClements Wasn't `.loc` undergoing deprecation? Pandas folks could have more info on it though, I just caught few rumors in air.

Comment: I'm never sure - I forget what's going on with all those accessors... was just off the top of my head - also, fairly sure one of them is slower than the other... so not even sure it's good advice... just throwing it out there as it came to mind

Comment: @Divakar it's `.ix` that's going: *Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.* So `.loc` is around for *purely label based indexing*

Comment: @JonClements Ah yes that's the one on the hitlist.

Comment: Thanks Bharath, that's the one I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.sign` to get the signs. Look for negative signs. Get the count of negative numbers for each column. Compare against the threshold of `1` to get a mask. Select the column names from the mask.

Hence, the implementation -

```
df1.columns[(np.sign(df1)<0).sum(0)<=1].tolist()
```

Or directly compare against `0` to replace the use of `np.sign` -

```
df1.columns[(df1<0).sum(0)<=1].tolist()
```

This gives us the column names. To select entire columns, other solutions I think have covered it.

Comment: Or maybe... `df1.columns[df1.lt(0).sum() == 1]`

Comment: @JonClements Yup that works too with `sum(0) `and `<=` corrections. Or we don't need that `sum(0)` part and `sum()` would suffice too?

Comment: @JonClements Ah `sum` is default to `0`, is it? Coming from NumPy I assumed sum(None) i.e. sum all elements that gives us a scalar.

Comment: You're right about the `<= 1` though - I read it as *exactly one* negative - not *one or less*

Comment: Thanks, I see why you went for column names, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Or You can try :

```
df1.columns[(df1<0).sum(0).lt(1)]
Out[338]: Index(['X', 'Z'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: OP said columns. Not Rows.