# Applying an operation on a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From this question [Select column with only one negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222413/select-column-with-only-one-negative-value) I'm trying to use and change the solution to a list of dataframes and select the one that qualifies. Cannot make it work though.

In the example below I want to return the dataframe that has only one negative value or less in column 'Z'.

In this case df1.

Example;

```
 N = 5

 np.random.seed(0)

 df1 = pd.DataFrame(
         {'X':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
          'Y':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
          'Z':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
               })

 df2 = pd.DataFrame(
         {'X':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
          'Y':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
          'Z':np.random.uniform(-3,3,N),
               })

          X         Y         Z
0  0.292881  0.875365  1.750350
1  1.291136 -0.374477  0.173370
2  0.616580  2.350638  0.408267
3  0.269299  2.781977  2.553580
4 -0.458071 -0.699351 -2.573784
----------------
          X         Y         Z
0 -2.477224  2.871710  0.839526
1 -2.878690  1.794951 -2.139880
2  1.995719 -0.231124  2.668014
3  1.668941  1.683175  0.131090
4  2.220073 -2.290353 -0.512028
```

How could I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure, given a list of dataframes `list_of_df = [df1, df2]` you want to return only the dataframes that has one or less negative values on a specific column?

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: So, for the sample just return first df?

Comment: yes, indeed, the complete dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the number of items under 0 using `sum` and just `yield` them.

```
def foo(df_list):
    for df in df_list:
        if (df['Z'] < 0).sum(0) <= 1:
            yield df
```

---

```
df_list = [df1, df2]
for df in foo(df_list):
    print(df)

          X         Y         Z
0  0.292881  0.875365  1.750350
1  1.291136 -0.374477  0.173370
2  0.616580  2.350638  0.408267
3  0.269299  2.781977  2.553580
4 -0.458071 -0.699351 -2.573784
```

Comment: Yeah, its the same really, I am using a fancy list compr.

Comment: @divakar; lol, just tried your solution and wanted to accept it, now its gone and has Alexander added a similar one

Comment: @Zanshin Essentially it's the same as this... it's upto you but the main thing is the `for df in df_list:
        if (df['Z'] < 0).sum(0) <= 1:` You can spin that however you want.

Comment: yeah, I know, do really like the one-liner though. I'll accept yours, thanks

Comment: @Zanshin The key difference is the generator used here by COLDSPEED vs the complete list generated via a comprehension.  If you were to process the dataframes that satisfied your conditions and then discard them, then the generator approach is preferable.  If you simply need a collection of them, then a list comprehension is generally faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a conditional list comprehension:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
>>> [df for df in dfs if df['Z'].lt(0).sum() <= 1]
[          X         Y         Z
 0  0.292881  0.875365  1.750350
 1  1.291136 -0.374477  0.173370
 2  0.616580  2.350638  0.408267
 3  0.269299  2.781977  2.553580
 4 -0.458071 -0.699351 -2.573784]
```

The result is a list of each dataframe that satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 0):

This would do

```
def func(dataframe_list, on_column):

    returned_list = []
    for df in dataframe_list:
        if (df[on_column] < 0).sum() <= 1:
            returned_list.append(df)

    return returned_list
```

In your case, call `func([df1, df2], on_column='Z')`